# Google sheets API: copy formula from cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

As none of the similar questions have real answers, I'll give it a try.

I'm using the Google Sheets API on a pre-existing spreadsheet.

I want to copy the formula in `A1`: `=A7/A2` to `B1`: `=B7/B2`

I can copy contents fine, but not formulas with this:

```py
body = {'values': [[result.get("values")[0]]]}
new_range = 'B1'
up_result = sheet.values().update(
spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=new_range, 
    valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body=body).execute()
```

Is there a way to copy the formula?

Comment: A developer created their [own `CopyFormulasDown` function](https://googlescripts.harryonline.net/copy-formulas-down) to mimic the same operation in Excel, if you choose to use their solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You want to copy the formula `=A7/A2` of cell "A1" to the cell "B1" as `=B7/B2`.
- You want to achieve this using Sheets API with google-api-python-client of Python.

  - From your script, I thought that you might use google-api-python-client with Python, although the tag of Python was not found.
- You have already been able to put and get values for Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, I used "CopyPasteRequest" of the method of spreadsheets.batchUpdate of Sheets API.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please set the variables of `spreadsheet_id` and `sheetId`.

```
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
spreadsheet_id = '###'  # Please set Spreadsheet ID.
sheetId = "###"  # Please set sheet ID.

batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "copyPaste": {
                "source": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "endRowIndex": 1,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                    "endColumnIndex": 1
                },
                "destination": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "endRowIndex": 1,
                    "startColumnIndex": 1,
                    "endColumnIndex": 2
                },
                "pasteType": "PASTE_FORMULA"
            }
        }
    ]
}
request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body)
response = request.execute()
print(response)
```

- Please set the range as the gridrange.

  - `0, 1, 0, 1` for `startRowIndex`, `endRowIndex`, `startColumnIndex` and `endColumnIndex` mean the cell "A1".
  - `0, 1, 1, 2` for `startRowIndex`, `endRowIndex`, `startColumnIndex` and `endColumnIndex` mean the cell "B1".

#### Result:

- When above script is run under that the cell of "A1" has `=A7/A2`, `=B7/B2` is put to the cell "B1".

#### Note:

- In above script, the authorization process is omitted. Please be careful this. So about this, please use your script.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [CopyPasteRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#copypasterequest)
- [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange)
- [Spreadsheet ID](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts?hl=en#spreadsheet_id)
- [Sheet ID](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts?hl=en#sheet_id)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Is it more complex than simply using an array formula?

=arrayformula(A7:7/A2:2)

If you only want it to go to B (or another set column), you can use this:

=arrayformula(A7:B7/A2:B2)

And if you only want it to go as far as you have data in row 2, you can use this:

=arrayformula(if(isblank(A2:2),,A7:7/A2:2))

Comment: I actually experimented just a minute ago with a hyperlink `=HYPERLINK("https://mylink.com","my text")` and it worked... so, maybe? Though I'm sure it said in the docs that it couldn't do that