# Copying formula referencing a different sheet with updated cell references

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57409533/google-sheets-api-copy-formula-from-cell), except that the formula I am copying doesn't reference the cells in the same sheet, but reference cells in a different sheet.

For example, I have sheet 1 and 2 in a Google sheet file. For sheet 1:

```
A1: ='sheet 2'!A1 - 'sheet 2'!A2

B1: =' '
```

I would like to copy A1's formula to B1 so it looks like:

```
B1: ='sheet 2'!B1 - 'sheet 2'!B2
```

Obviously I can do this manually by dragging the + sign at the bottom right corner of A1 down to B1 in sheet 1. But how do I do this with sheet API?

I've tried the top rated solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57409533/google-sheets-api-copy-formula-from-cell), and it works if the formula references cells in the sheet 1. If the formula references cells in sheet 2, it does **copy the formula but won't update the cell reference**... the result would look like:

```
B1: ='sheet 2'!A1 - 'sheet 2'!A2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `indirect() + row()`

Comment: @TheMaster any suggestions on tags?

Comment: Tags:  It's already fixed by Ruben. Have you tried `repeatCell` request?

Comment: @TheMaster I am trying to repeat a cell from Row 3 to Row 2, but stuck on defining grid range to indicate which row is to be repeated to the rest. The startRowIndex has to be smaller than endRowIndex... Do you happen to know how to specify the row to be repeated if it's not the first row in the range definition?

Comment: repeatCell requires you provide the initial data. If  the data is already present, use [`autofill request`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#autofillrequest). Here range will be the entire range row 2:3. You can skip source  and destination

Comment: autoFill seems to work in my quick testing! Let me check and report back tomorrow morning. Thanks! @TheMaster

Comment: @TheMaster autoFill request worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`autofill request`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#autofillrequest) to simulate autofill(i.e., dragging the + sign at the bottom right corner of A1 down)